# How can you make Angular2 work in a generated distribution folder?

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp, angular, systemjs

I'm trying to get my own starter project for Angular2+Typescript (+SystemJS+Gulp4) going, but I've run into some problems when switching from compiling the TypeScript in the same folder as the JavaScript and with access to `node_modules` folder to putting everything in a `dist` folder (with `dist/js` for compiled JavaScript and `dist/js/lib` for the vendor files (`angular2.dev.js`, `http.dev.js`, `router.dev.js`, `Rx.js`, `system.src.js` etc.)).

You can find the complete project [on github (souldreamer/event-planner)](https://github.com/souldreamer/event-planner).

Is someone willing to take a gander and see what I'm doing wrong? It's probably the `SystemJS` config in `index.html` because depending on what config I try, I either get no actual loading of `boot.js` (the network tab shows that everything was loaded though, but the `System.import()` promise never resolves), or errors like `core_1.Component is not a function` or `core_1.Input is not a function` when I also add the `InputComponent`.

**Note:** before you think about marking this as a duplicate, I've been searching the net & StackOverflow for the past couple of days, and tried every variation I could find, so it's not really a duplicate problem (even though there are *many* similar questions).

Included here are some pieces I think might be relevant, in case you don't want to look at the full project:

- `TypeScript` compilation (`Gulp4` task):

  ```
  function tsCompile() {
    var tsResult = gulp
      .src(['./app/**/*.ts', './typings/**/*.ts'])
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(tsc(tsc.createProject('tsconfig.json')));

    return merge([
      tsResult.dts.pipe(gulp.dest('./typings/typescriptApp.d.ts')),
      tsResult.js
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'))
    ]);
  }
  ```
- `tsconfig.json`

  ```
  {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "dist/js",
      "target": "ES5",
      "module": "system",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "removeComments": false,
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
    },
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
  }
  ```
- `index.html`

  ```
  <head>
    <base href="/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- inject:libs -->
    <!--   add wanted libs to gulpfile -->
    <!--   this is replaced by the gulp task runner -->
    <!--   lib order: -->
    <!--     angular2-polyfills, system.src, Rx, -->
    <!--     angular2.dev, router.dev, http.dev -->
    <!-- endinject -->
    <script>
      System.config({
        baseUrl: './', // same result with this omitted
        transpiler: 'typescript', // same result with this omitted
        defaultJSExtensions: true,
        bundles: {
          './js/lib/angular2.dev.js': ['angular2/*']
        },
        packages: {
          js: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        },
        paths: {
          'angular/http': './js/lib/router.dev.js',
          'angular/router': './js/lib/http.dev.js',
          'angular2/*': './js/lib/angular2.dev.js',
          'rx/*': './js/lib/Rx.js'
        }
      });
      System.import('js/boot')
        .then(
          function() {console.log('loaded')},
          console.error.bind(console)
        );
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <main-app>Loading...</main-app>
  </body>

  </html>
  ```
- `boot.ts` (the actual `Angular2` app is inconsequential, it should work as-is, the error is not here, included for completeness' sake)

  ```
  import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
  import {AppComponent} from './components/app.component';

  bootstrap(AppComponent, []);
  ```
- `app.component.ts` (the actual `Angular2` app is inconsequential, it should work as-is, the error is not here, included for completeness' sake)

  ```
  import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
  import {InputComponent} from './input.component';

  @Component({
    selector: 'main-app',
    template: `<h1>Hi!</h1>
    <input-component label="A"></input-component>
    <input-component label="B"></input-component>
    `,
    directives: [InputComponent]
  })
  export class AppComponent {

  }
  ```
- `input.component.ts` (the actual `Angular2` app is inconsequential, it should work as-is, the error is not here, included for completeness' sake)

  ```
  import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';

  @Component({
    selector: 'input-component',
    template: `
      <label [attr.for]="inputName">{{label}}
      <input #input [attr.id]="inputName" type="text"></label>
    `,
    styles: [
      `label { color: red; }`
    ]
  })
  export class InputComponent {
    public static latestId: number = 0;
    private inputId: number = InputComponent.latestId;
    @Input() public label: string = '';

    constructor() {
      InputComponent.latestId++;
    }
    get inputName(): string {
      return 'input-' + this.inputId;
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: any particular reason for compiling with babel and not typescript?

Comment: Gulp has built-in support for babel, I don't have to transpile the gulpfile before I can run gulp. If I'd written my gulpfile in TypeScript I'd have had to transpile before being able to run it (to my knowledge). So pure laziness :D

Comment: why would you want to transpile a gulp file? sorry I'm a bit lost

Comment: The Gulp+Babel thing is only for the gulpfile task. It's a `gulpfile.babel.js`. I'll edit it to remove the confusion, as it doesn't really matter if it's a babel gulpfile or not for the snippet included. And there might be reasons why you'd want to transpile a gulpfile (probably similar reasons as the ones I have for using ES6 in my gulpfile: it makes writing tasks easier and more elegant in my point of view)

Comment: got it, so what's the exact error you are getting when you load your index.html file?

Comment: With all of the code as shown in the question, I get: `core_1.Input is not a function`

Comment: are you compiling the typings?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100510/discussion-between-ionut-costica-and-langley).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the solution, the `System.config()` parameters were wrong. This is the working version for whoever has similar problems:

```
    System.config({
      packages: {
        js: {
          format: 'register',
          defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
      }
    });
```

The rest of it apparently takes care of itself.